# HTML5 FullScreen API toggle with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

I am trying to make a button that would toggle (on/off) HTML5 fullscreen on a certain website.

After reading plenty of documentation, it appears there still are some inconsistencies among how browsers treat certain properties for it.

I went for kind of "cross-browser" approach which **does** work in Firefox and Safari/MacOS, partially works in Safari/Windows and totally fails to work in Chrome and Opera.

Some castrated code snippets:

```
// class init
initialize: function() {

    this.elmButtonFullscreen = $('fullscreen');
    this.elmButtonFullscreen.on('click', this.onClickFullscreen.bindAsEventListener(this));
},

// helper methods
_launchFullScreen: function(element) {

    if(element.requestFullScreen) { element.requestFullScreen(); }
    else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) { element.mozRequestFullScreen(); }
    else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { element.webkitRequestFullScreen(); }
},
_cancelFullScreen: function() {

    if(document.cancelFullScreen) { document.cancelFullScreen(); }
    else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) { document.mozCancelFullScreen(); }
    else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) { document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); }
},
_isFullScreen: function() {

    fullScreen = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ? true : false;
    if(this.debug) console.log('Fullscreen enabled? ' + fullScreen);
    return fullScreen;
},

// callbacks
onClickFullscreen: function(e) {

    e.stop();
    if(this._isFullScreen()) this._cancelFullScreen();
    else this._launchFullScreen(document.documentElement);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the 1st line of `_isFullScreen` function to

```
fullScreen = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ? true : false;
```

Does the trick (at least for Firefox, Chrome and Safari on Mac and Windows)

Comment: At least in FF24, it's mozFullScreenEnabled (screen with capital s)

Comment: Also not, that is _isFullScreen returns if a browser is capable of displaying fullscreen, not if fullscreen is currently active. You need to listen for document.fullscreenElement and the browser variants for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
function goFullScreen() {
  const el = document.documentElement,
      rfs = el.requestFullScreen
        || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
        || el.mozRequestFullScreen
        || el.msRequestFullscreen

  rfs.call(el)
}

document.querySelector('#full-screen-button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    goFullScreen()
  })
```

Keep in mind that requesting `fullScreen` needs to be done via a user-triggered event such as a *click event* - `mousedown`,`mouseup` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Based on what [I found on Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) the function for Webkit is actually spelt slightly different.

`document.webkitRequestFullscreen` with a lowercase "s" for screen.

And [from W3 spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-requestfullscreen), it is meant to be with a lowercase "s".

On the MDN link they say:

*Note: The specification uses the label, "Fullscreen" as in "requestFullscreen" or "fullscreenEnabled" - without a capital 's'. The implementation described here and other prefixed implementations may use a capital 'S'.*

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I believe I've been there before, but that's not the main issue here; Safari/Mac still manages to launch fullscreen without problems.

What I just checked is that Chrome answers `true` to `document.webkitFullscreenEnabled` even if we're not in the fullscreen view. Any clues? :)

Comment: Some playing around in the Chrome Console shows me that the `document` object doesn't actually have the `webkitRequestFullscreen` function however `document.documentElement` does. While I still couldn't get it to work yet, I thought I might mention that.

Comment: Looks like there might be some vital clues:
http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/

Going to test it now.

Comment: I found a demo that worked in Chrome with the fullscreen API and I think it might only work if done in a `click` event. That is a great link by the way.

Comment: Okay - according to what I found out - Chrome treats `document.webkitFullscreenEnabled` as if "do we support fullscreen mode?" and `document.webkitIsFullScreen` as answering the question "are we in fullscreen mode?".

Love them browser quirks, don't we? :)

Comment: Definitely! Further looking into this demo in Chrome, it does only work on a click event and calling it from the console does nothing.

Comment: For it working on click event only - it is kind of understandable. Imagine what over-advertised sites could do if going fullscreen would be available from regular function calls...