# Create a web page without window title bar

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window, popupwindow

This is an updated question based on feedback from "glautrou":  I have an LCD Cape coming for a BeagleBone Black single board computer and I want to have a web page displayed on the LCD with no borders, no scroll bars, and NO TITLE BAR.   I am experimenting with getting this to work using the below code which was cut down from an example located  at http://lesson8.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/html5-fullscreen-api.html.

My desire is to have this run either when the page loads or from within a script...and NOT requiring the press of a button.   The below script works fine with the button but does not work with either the open or script invocations.  I will admit now that I don't really understand the DOM so I suspect that I am missing something simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<BODY onLoad="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);">
<h1>HTML5 Fullscreen API</h1>

<div style="padding:20px;">
    <button onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);" class="sexyButton">Launch Fullscreen</button>
    <button onclick="cancelFullscreen();" class="sexyButton">Hide Fullscreen</button>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}

function cancelFullscreen() {
  if(document.cancelFullScreen) {
    document.cancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
  }
}

launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);

//]]>  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific fullscreen API in HTML5, look at [HTML5 FullScreen API toggle with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371504/html5-fullscreen-api-toggle-with-javascript) and [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/).

Comment: glautrou:  Thanks this got me a lot further but I hit another bump and am either missing something simple or HTML5 is blocking full screen unless user initiated?

Comment: When you call your JavaScript function your page is directly displayed full screen, but the browser automatically display a pop-up for approving/denying your application to be displayed in full screen. This is to prevent applications to abuse because the fullscreen behaviour can be very annoying for end-users (lost tabs, Windows taskbar...). Perhaps you may be interest to display your content in a new [about:blank](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus) windows

Comment: I have been coming to that conclusion...I recognize that I may be in the slim majority of people that would like to use a browser as the UI for an embedded application...but...it would be nice if the browser would allow full screen without a user request if if saw that we were running on localhost!  It feels like my first user interaction is going to have to be a standard form that has a button that takes us full screen without the extra garbage cluttering my small LCD.

Comment: You can call the fullscrean method in JavaScript when your page loads. If the user is happy that your website is displayed like this he will check the checkbox to add an exception to the browser. If you only want to be fullscreen on your machine you can press F11.

Comment: My final solution is posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had lost sight of the fact that I am running an embedded (single user) application here...when that re-occurred to me I looked for a way to send keystrokes to the browser.   I found, and installed, xdotool as it was packaged for angstrom, and wrote a little autostart script.   It works a charm though I will now automate it a little better via my node.js application.  Thanks for the help, Will

Answer (score 0):

Another way to meet my requirement given that I am running Chrome...

chrome.exe --kiosk --incognito some.web.site

Kiosk does the full screen thing and incognito prevents the question about restoring sessions in the case of an ungraceful shutdown.

This is what I needed regardless of what I may have thought that I needed!